# What should be the address of my image upload folder?

Tags: php

This is where my upload.php is located

```
xampp/htdocs/site/admin/upload.php
```

I want to upload images to this address

```
xampp/htdocs/site/img
```

I am using this code by [W3schools in upload.php](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

I need to change this code in upload.php file, but confused, what is my `img` folder address

```
$target_dir = "img/";
```

What to write in this ^^^^^^

Comment: Does `../img/` work?

Comment: worked, u r legend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `../img/`.

`..` means the parent directory, so going from `xampp/htdocs/site/admin/` to `xampp/htdocs/site/`. From here, you just need the `img/` directory.